# Internet Explorer prompting to download Citrix application shortcut

Tags: internet-explorer-9, citrix

A user on Windows 7 with Internet Explorer 9 can use our Citrix apps without a problem when he logs into Citrix from a URL like:  http://internal.domain.com.  He uses this URL whenever he is connected to the LAN or WAN.

However, if he disconnects from the WAN, and connects on the public internet, he needs to login to Citrix from a different URL like: https://external.domain.com, as the internal URL is only for LAN or WAN IP addresses.

After he logs into to this second website, any time he clicks on a Citrix shortcut Internet Explorer prompts him to save or open the .ICA file.  If he chooses to open the file, the file will start to download, but the download never completes, so he is never able to open the file.  If he chooses to download the file, the download will still never complete.

He is using the same user account both times.  Both website URLs above are in the Trusted Sites list in Internet Explorer.  The only difference is that when he is inside the LAN or WAN, Internet Explorer needs to go through a proxy server to connect to the first URL.

I have uninstalled the web client, and reinstalled it using a fresh copy of the installation file, but the issue remains.

All other instances of Windows 7 are able to connect and launch applications when logged into the external Citrix URL.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue with IE9](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX129082).

However, after applying the workaround in the article the .ICA file can be downloaded completely, but opening it does not open the Citrix Application.

Nothing happens, except wfcrun32.exe opens in Task Manager as soon as the link is clicked (before opening), and once the download is finished, wfica32.exe opens for about a second and then disappears.

This issue only happens on 1 of our citrix websites. The other website functions perfectly, even though it is being opened by IE9.

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at the resulting ICA, whether all fields are valid and whether another win7 machine can start the session by running that file. If it is so, you'll need citrix support involvement. Sometimes citrix applications produce debugging output strings - try catching it with SysInternals DbgView application

Comment: I ran the receiver update at the link above and this fixed my connection problems.

Answer (score 1):

make yourself a batch file containing this (or pointing to the folder containing wfica32.exe):

`cd\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\ICA Client\`

`wfica32.exe /setup`

this will re-register the client and you will have to open a new IE session from the start menu, NOT from the quick launch.  Also, it may be necessary to end-task the citrix processes.

Comment: This did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the steps below

- install the latest Citrix receiver
- restart the computer
- start the Internet Explorer
- clear all the cache and temp files etc. in Internet Explorer
- start the Citrix

It will work. Before the last step you should put the website (through which you launch the `.ica` file) under Trusted Sites.